# Using optparse in Python

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, customization, optparse

Is there a way I can configure **optparse** in Python to not take the beginning **-**? So instead of

```
%program -d optionvalue
```

I get

```
%program d optionvalue
```

Currently, when I try to do

```
parser.add_option('d', '--database')
```

i get the following error:

```
optparse.OptionError: invalid option string 'd': must be at least two characters long
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do this? That is breaking convention. How are you going to distinguish between argument `d` and value `d`?  (e.g. `program d d`)

Answer (score 6):

In short, no.

> an argument used to supply extra
>   information to guide or customize the
>   execution of a program. There are many
>   different syntaxes for options; the
>   traditional Unix syntax is a hyphen
>   (“-“) followed by a single letter,
>   e.g. -x or -F. Also, traditional Unix
>   syntax allows multiple options to be
>   merged into a single argument, e.g. -x
>   -F is equivalent to -xF. The GNU project introduced -- followed by a
>   series of hyphen-separated words, e.g.
>   --file or --dry-run. **These are the only two option syntaxes provided by
>   optparse.**

http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#terminology

You would have to parse that yourself.

Comment: Yes, seems that even 'XX' doesnt work as I get the following error:
    optparse.OptionError: invalid short option string 'dd': must be of the form -x, (x any non-dash char)

Answer (score 1):

`parse_args()` allows you to provide your own argument list, not just using `sys.argv[1:]`, which it uses by default. So you could preprocess the commandline arguments, and then pass them to optargs. Assuming you want all 1-character arguments to count as option keys:

```
orig_args = sys.argv[1:]
new_args = []
for arg in orig_args:
    if len(arg) == 1:
        arg = '-' + arg
    new_args.append(arg)

(options, args) = parser.parse_args(new_args)
```

(you could also subclass `OptionParser` and put it there)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to force  with use callback action:

http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#callback-example-6-variable-arguments

which gives you raw access to left and right args